# PHP ldap_bind() failure

Tags: php, docker, ldap

I am running one of my apps on php and at one point in the code I'm using ldap for authenticating users. Below is the code.

```
<?php
session_start();
// error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
// $username = $_POST['username'];
// $password = $_POST['password'];

$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxxx";

$ldapconfig['host'] = "xxxx";
$ldapconfig['port'] = "xxxx";
$ldapconfig['basedn'] = 'xxxxx';
$ldapconfig['usersdn'] = 'xxxx';
$ds=ldap_connect($ldapconfig['host'],$ldapconfig['port']);


ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT, 10);

$dn="uid=".$username.",".$ldapconfig['usersdn'].",".$ldapconfig['basedn'];
if ($bind=ldap_bind($ds, $dn, $password)) {
  $_SESSION['username']=$username;
  echo 'true';
} else {
  echo 'false';
}
?>
```

This code works perfectly fine on my mac , and authenticates successfully. However when I build and deploy it in a centos docker it starts failing with the the below error.

```
PHP Warning:  ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in /tmp/auth1.php on line 21
```

On my mac the php version is PHP 7.3.24 and on the docker the version is PHP 7.0.33 . Even though its different I don't think there should be much change in the functionality of ldap_bind().
Can anyone tell what's going wrong here?

Comment: FYI I am installing the php70w-ldap package on docker to use the php ldap functionalities.

Comment: It could be a network issue (depending on where the ldap server is actually running). If you ssh into your centos vm, can you reach your ldap server from there (ie. using netcat `nc <ldapserverip> <ldap-port> -v` or via telnet or even better using ldapsearch) ?

Comment: @EricLavault its not a network issue i can connect.

Comment: Ok, another idea: on CentOS you may have SELinux running and preventing httpd scripts/modules to connect to the network. You can momentarily disable it or `setenforce 0` (put SELinux in permissive mode) to see if it changes something. If it does then it is probably related to the selinux boolean "httpd_can_network_connect", you can enable it (allows httpd scripts to connect to the network) with `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`.

Comment: @EricLavault thanks for the answer . how can i change this. In my centos docker i dont see setenforce or setsebool commands. Is there any file where I can go and change?

Comment: It depends on your system, on centos the config should be in `/etc/selinux/config`. But it is better to use commands rather than editing the config, the commands are packaged with "libselinux-utils" `yum install libselinux-utils`.

Comment: im not sure if selinux is enabled, there is no `config` file in `/etc/selinux`. only file I see in `/etc/selinux` are `semanage.conf  tmp`

Comment: @EricLavault Also from the docker where i deployed, when i am running the auth script separately using php it runs successfully all the time. Only when my app is up using `httpd` and then when i try to login it fails 50% percent of the time with the above error. Also as i said earlier on my mac i never saw that issue

Comment: If it works 100% via php cli, and 50% of the time via httpd (it changes a lot of things you should mention it in your post), then it's not selinux.